# Select feature one by one and save it as image using python script

Tags: select, qgis

I have used following code for selecting the features one by one. but when i run the script it is just selecting last feature and zoom it. I want to select each feature and zoom it.

```
def SelectFeatures(self):
layer = self.iface.activeLayer();
iter = layer.getFeatures();
for feature in iter:
    geom = feature.geometry()
    self.iface.mapCanvas().setSelectionColor(QColor("yellow"));
    layer.setSelectedFeatures([feature.id()])
    selected_features = layer.selectedFeatures()
    self.iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected( layer )
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
    path = 'D:\Test'+ str(feature.id()) + '.png'
    self.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage(path)
    #QMessageBox.information(None, "DEBUG:", str(path))
```

Now, the zooming process is too quick due to that i am not able to see the selected feature zoomed. in addition to that the image which is generated is the same every time. 
My objective is to achieve following things.

1. Select Feature.
2. Zoom selected feature.
3. Save image.

Repeat the steps for rest of the features.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kludge... but have you tried sleeping?

```
def SelectFeatures(self):
layer = self.iface.activeLayer();
iter = layer.getFeatures();
for feature in iter:
    geom = feature.geometry()
    self.iface.mapCanvas().setSelectionColor(QColor("yellow"));
    layer.setSelectedFeatures([feature.id()])
    selected_features = layer.selectedFeatures()
    self.iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected( layer )
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
    path = 'D:\Test'+ str(feature.id()) + '.png'

    import time
    time.sleep(5) # delays for 5 seconds

    self.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage(path)
    #QMessageBox.information(None, "DEBUG:", str(path))
```